# .NET MAUI: Change off color of switch

Tags: maui, switchcontrol

is there an opportunity to change the off color of a switch control? I can change ThumbColor or OnColor, but unfortunately not OffColor.

When switch is not toggled, you can't see the complete switch control very good:
[image: Example]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, when the switch is toggled change the colours. The initial colours based on your default can be set in OnAppearing().

In xaml.

```
<Switch BackgroundColor="#f9f9f9" IsToggled="{Binding ActiveFlightText}" OnColor="LightGreen" Toggled="sendActiveText_Toggled" />enter code here
```

And in code behind:

```
private void sendActiveText_Toggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
{
    Switch activeText = (Switch)sender;

    if(activeText.IsToggled)
    {
        activeText.ThumbColor = Colors.Green;
    }
    else
    {
        activeText.ThumbColor = Colors.Red;
    }
}:
```

Comment: He is asking about changing the dark blue color in the picture, not the color of the thumb

Answer (score 0):

> When switch is not toggled, you can't see the complete switch control
> very good.

The background color set for the switch affects the visual effect.

You can try to set to another color.

Please refer to the following code:

```
        <Switch OnColor="Orange"  
                BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke"
                ThumbColor="Green" 
                Toggled="Switch_Toggled" />
```

Comment: This is ok, but now I have a big white rectangle in background. So there is no possibility to only set the color of the switch control when its off?

Comment: You can set the `BackgroundColor` property of `Switch` to the same or similar color of the background color of your page, then there will be no such rectangle.

Comment: `So there is no possibility to only set the color of the switch control when its off?` There is no such relative property for us to set for the switch control when its off.