# .Net Maui Switch visual state manager will not change OnColor for Off state

Tags: android, maui, visualstatemanager

Just implementing a switch into a display which has a black background on Android.

Added a Switch managed to set OnColor and ThumbColor for On State and Thumbcolor for Off State, but no matter were I tinker I can not set the Oncolor for the off state using visual state manager (hope that makes sense).

As you can see in the image below, the on State is green, the off state shows nothing it melds into the black background. I want to set that as grey.

[image]

My Switch

```
<Switch IsToggled="True" Style="{StaticResource ToggleSwitch}">
```

In My Styles.xaml I have added my custom style.

```
    <Style x:Key ="ToggleSwitch" TargetType="Switch">
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="On">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="OnColor"
                            Value="Green" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Off">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="OnColor"
                            Value="Gray" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I have seen other answers suggesting changing Background and Backgroundcolor, this is not the answer as the background has to be black. No matter what I try I can not change the off state color at all.

Any suggestions/pointers as always appreciated.

Reference:
[.NET MAUI: Change off color of switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74712389/net-maui-change-off-color-of-switch) <-- This answer is no good at all.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/switch#switch-visual-states

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/visual-states

contemplating using a custom solution at this rate :-
https://github.com/IeuanWalker/Maui.Switch

But would much rather use native or as near as possible to native.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This what you ask for is done with platform specific code. I am sorry.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply, much appreciated. Just gutting not being able to target the most simple of visual elements to change a colour.

Comment: Its strange that gray isn't the default. But I agree, there should be an "OffColor" property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No matter what I try I cannot change the Off state color at all.

This is because natively [Switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.switch?view=net-maui-7.0) only has `OnColor` Property which can only get or set the color of the switch when it is in the `On` position. So it would be perfect when there would be a BindableProperty `OffColor` to set for Switch.

However, you can raise a feature request:https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/new/choose for adding a BindableProperty `OffColor` to set for Switch.

As an alternative workaround, you can use the custom solution as you mentioned:https://github.com/IeuanWalker/Maui.Switch. I checked the sample code, you can change the Off state color via `CustomSwitch_SwitchPanUpdate` method:

```
static void CustomSwitch_SwitchPanUpdate(CustomSwitch customSwitch, SwitchPanUpdatedEventArgs e) 
{
       //Switch Color Animation
        Color fromSwitchColor = e.IsToggled ? Color.FromArgb("#6200ee") : Color.FromArgb("#fafafa");
        Color toSwitchColor = e.IsToggled ? Color.FromArgb("#fafafa") : Color.FromArgb("#6200ee");

        Color fromColor = e.IsToggled ? Color.FromArgb("#00ff00") : Color.FromArgb("#808080");
        Color toColor = e.IsToggled ? Color.FromArgb("#808080") : Color.FromArgb("#00ff00");

        double t = e.Percentage * 0.01;

        customSwitch.KnobBackgroundColor = ColorAnimationUtil.ColorAnimation(fromSwitchColor, toSwitchColor, t);
        customSwitch.BackgroundColor = ColorAnimationUtil.ColorAnimation(fromColor, toColor, t);
}
```

**Output which has a black background:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Alexander, Yes it does look like a custom solution for the time being is the best option. I am going to suggest it be added to the feature set, maybe one day we will be editing this to say it has been implented !

Comment: No worries, Andy! Hopefully it'll be implemented soon! :)